# Modeling a workout schedule using OOP(DDD specifically)

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design, entity

I am just getting into DDD, and I am trying to model a very basic exercise schedule. I have a `Schedule` and I have a `Slot` the slot takes 0 - many `Exercise` entities. The schedule is composed of Slots which must be a minimum of 7 to match up to a week but I don't want to prevent users from having a schedule that exceeds a week (not entirely sure where I am going with that just yet). So when a user constructs a `Schedule` they must pass an array of seven slots which some can be empty to signify when you have a day off. Say you have the following schedule...

```
Monday Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday Friday    Saturday Sunday
Legs   OFF     Chest/Back    OFF    Shoulders   OFF     OFF
```

So as of right now it doesn't matter what time of day it is so a calendar model seems like over kill, and it also doesn't really have to line up with a specific day either as long as it follows the 1 on 1 off, etc. pattern. They could start it off on a Sunday or whatever day they decide to start it on.

My question is does it make sense to have empty slots in this model, and is the idea of simply having a schedule composed of slots optionally filled with exercises enough to model this?

**EDIT**:

Here is a start to a UML diagram. Again, I am more interested in the model of the schedule itself whether or not having an array of slots is the best way to go about it. I have taken into consideration a comment about just modelling what I need specifically the Slot no longer has an OFF day in the model, but I am still thinking about that part. [image]

Comment: You ask this question as if the API (i.e. business logic parameter inputs) should drive your entire design. It really, really shouldn't. How you structure things internally is wholly unrelated to how (and in what shape) input is delivered to the business logic.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean that the business logic parameter inputs drive the design here. I will update the question to have more details, but I haven't even thought about an API for this for that matter, but when you are creating a program for an exercise routine you have a Schedule that repeats itself weekly and you repeat that schedule for a duration for example 12 weeks. I would say the concept of having a schedule is pretty central to the given domain of exercise programming as is the idea of OFF days. What makes you say that this structure is driven by input parameters? @Flater

Comment: _"So when a user constructs a Schedule they must pass an array of seven slots"_

Comment: Yeah you are right. I think in trying to explain it I did think about the domain logic from a user or client's standpoint i.e. what will the application service have to do to create it. However, that is more to illustrate the point that it should have a schedule that mimics the structure of a week, and how exactly it is best to model that I am unsure of which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to map a schedule-slot to a particular day, and this is why you expect 7 slots.  This is why you have an issue with getting less slots and why you can't see a use of more slots.

The empty slot is just a workaround to address the weakness of this design. It may not be a good idea. Instead, consider adding to your domain model some elements of date (e.g. a weekday, a time-interval, etc.) associated with the slot.

Moreover, expecting all the slots to be defined immediately at creation of the schedule does not seem to match the reality: a customer/member decides to do some sport (i.e. create an account and an empty schedule), then he/she will start to populate the schedule with some slots, then probably the customer will add or remove slots or change exercises as progress are made (or boredom steps in). This does not prevent to provide encouragement to the user if there are too few slots.

So review the operations of the schedule to separate the concerns of creating it from managing its content. Or is there any constraint that could justify to have the full schedule from the start?

Unfortunately, you do not describe your current entities, their properties and operations, their aggregates and the expected invariants, so it's difficult to provide more specific advise.  Edit your question to add this missing info if needed.

Comment: So in the context of this domain it is from the perspective of a `Trainer` which puts together a program for a `Trainee` and this program will have a duration, but I left out some details(will add more to the question in a little while). 

The `Schedule` has the notion of an empty slot because more often than not you don't train 7 days a week. I wanted to have that as an actual concept in the model as a trainee needs to know when they have the day off, and I don't want the client(Application Service) to have to populate nulls or empty array of exercises or something of the sort.

Comment: @user3832583 It’s a question of point of view: personally, I try to remember what I want to do and not what I don’t want to do. The empty slots is not something that I plan, but what’s remaining after my plans. And for the trainer it’s the opposite: the free slots are places where he/she can propose activities. But again, it’s not solething you plan, except if you train an elite team, in which case you may plan rest days before important competitions. :-)

Comment: Yeah I have for now removed the concept of an off day and updated the question with a UML diagram if you want to check that out that be great :) In terms of implementation what would you suggest for the schedule portion? I have added a day enum so you can specify where in the schedule it falls and it just assumes if there are missing days it is an off day.